# mysql concat and substring_index in where clause

Tags: mysql, sql, substring, concatenation

I have a value in table that I am selecting from that is in the following format:

```
day_shared =
    12_month
    3_month
    1_week
```

I need to use this to a function in DATE_ADD(), this is the code i have so far but it seems to error out and im not sure what i am doing wrong. Would greatly appreciate some help/advice

```
WHERE
    NOW() <  DATE_ADD(date_posted, INTERVAL CONCAT(CONVERT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared,'_', 1), SIGNED INTEGER),' ',UPPER(SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared,'_', -1))))
```

Solution tried from Gordon:

```
NOW() < DATE_ADD(
  date_posted, 
  (
    CASE WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_week' THEN INTERVAL (
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared , '_', 1) + 0
    ) WEEK WHEN day_shared  LIKE '%_month' SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared , '_', 1) + 0 DAY THEN INTERVAL (
      SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared , '_', 1) + 0
    ) MONTH END
  )
) 


Something is wrong in your syntax '(
  CASE WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_week' THEN INTERVAL (
    SUBSTRING' on line 8
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that the `day` in `interval 1 day` is a SQL keyword, not a string.  So you cannot parse it from a column name.

So, you can instead use a `CASE` expression to handle different time units:

```
WHERE  NOW() <  (CASE WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_day'
                      THEN date_posted + INTERVAL (SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared, '_', 1) + 0) DAY
                      WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_week'
                      THEN date_posted + INTERVAL (SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared, '_', 1) + 0) WEEK
                      WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_month'
                      THEN date_posted + INTERVAL (SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared, '_', 1) + 0) MONTH
                  END)
```

This syntax [works](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=1fc41ecff5cbcfe837d273d03acd3998).

Comment: my bad! the case is that it can only be month and week

Comment: @tomaskeller - Then add another level to the case expression checking for strings that end with `_week`??

Comment: I have, but still get error for some reason

Comment: edited the question, added what error i get

Comment: I'm not convinced that this is possible without using dynamic sql (create the sql statement as a string dynamically, then execute it on the fly), as the outcome of the case statement would be an sql keyword, not an sql data type.

Comment: @Shadow would you mind showing me an example? or point to somewhere?

Comment: @tomaskeller . . . My bad.  A `case` expression cannot return an `interval`.  I fixed the answer.

Answer (score 0):

```
NOW()
<
CASE
  WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_week'
    THEN
      DATE_ADD(
        date_posted,
        INTERVAL (SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared , '_', 1) + 0) WEEK
      )
  WHEN day_shared LIKE '%_month'
    THEN
      DATE_ADD(
        date_posted,
        INTERVAL (SUBSTRING_INDEX(day_shared , '_', 1) + 0) MONTH
      )
END
```

Comment: @tomaskeller - You'd still probably be better off storing the result of the calculation in a column.  In fact, store the calculation result ***instead of*** the string being used.